# Grafana on Kubernetes : Is it a good practice to source control every configuration of datasource and dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, azure-aks, argocd

Architecture Overview:

We have Grafana running on Azure Kubernetes Service and Persistent Storage has been enabled.

We store the Grafana Helm value file in git and use ArgoCD for CD.

**Now we are in a situation where we should store all dashboards and data sources config in the Helm values file or not.**

**Advantage:**

- In case something is wrong with the persistent storage (e.g. disaster, someone deletes all Grafana resources), we can easily re-create Grafana resources.

**Disadvantages:**

1. If a user would like to modify a data source, he/she has to notify the Grafana admin to update the Helm value file, then have a normal code review process to apply the change. So the users have to wait for a certain amount of time for a tiny little change.
2. Later we may have more Grafana users, they may just create new data sources or dashboards as they wish. We just cannot source control everything.

I was wondering is there a common best practice for this situation? Or it really depends on our own situation?

Thanks!